# How to revert the SVN trunk and put it in a branch?

Tags: svn, version-control

I haven't used branches in SVN (although I have in GIT). I committed some changes to trunk and that became revision 1082. I now realise I should have branched at the previous revision so I can work on the 1082 changes for a while. So... I need to backtrack the trunk to 1081 and make the changes I posted for 1082 into a branch. I also have unposted changes that I want to post onto the new branch. Should I just commit those first and then sort out the branching?

I can probably do this with file copies, reverts etc. Is there a 'normal' way to do this in svn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a 'normal' way to do this in svn?

Yes, there is. Please, read the documentation: [SVNBook | Branching and Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.html).

Generally speaking there are several different approaches, but I would try the following:

1. Undo revision 1082 and commit this change to the repository. Read [Undoing Changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo).
2. Create a branch out of trunk. Read [Creating a Branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.using.html#svn.branchmerge.using.create).
3. Run cherry-pick merge to copy revision 1081 to the new branch. Read [Cherrypicking](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.cherrypicking).

Comment: I need 1082 (plus changes not committed) in the new branch. So should I: Commit changes to create 1085, undo to 1081, create a branch from 1085.

Comment: @Rob If you undo 1082, it will still be in the repository and will be mergeable to branch. Revisions in SVN are *immutable*. As of local uncommitted changes -- generate a patch and apply it to your new branch after cherry-picking r1082.

Comment: I think the immutable part was missing from my musings. I done it now, thanks.